# How can I edit color, font, bg_color of specific cells in my table using css

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html table and have been trying to change the fonts and colours of specific cells but cant seem to do it.

Here is my table, all I have for my css on this table is shown.

```css
 table,
 th,
 td {
   border: solid;
   font-family: Mylius;
   font-size: 12px;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <td colspan="3">Baggage allowance</td>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="800px">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Passenger</td>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test adult</td>
    <td>46kg</td>
  </tr>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="450px">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Test infant</td>
    <td>23kg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">All baggage should have handles</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search for css styles should explain this to you. You should do a more thorough effort before asking questions. Anyway here is the basics:

You can set the style inline directly on the cell:

```
<td bgcolor="#FF00FF" style="font-family:courier">Test adult</td>
```

Or set a class on the specific cells you want to change and create a css rule.

```
<td class="red">Test adult</td>
```

and put the following inside your css file:

```
td.red {
  background: red
}
```

Comment: Please do not use such old attributes as bgcolor. If you MUST be inline, use the style attribute - it has been available since 1998 and you even have it for the font

Answer (score 0):

Make changes inline. Like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000">January</td>
    <td bgcolor="#00FF00">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is highly pre 1999

Comment: So are tables. 

You can follow this as well. Same answer I gave earlier.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_bgcolor.asp

Comment: W3schools.com is a horrific "resource"

Comment: The same solution is provided in the link you referred to: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/why-css-styling-is-for-tables-too/

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of what you are trying to do here:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/why-css-styling-is-for-tables-too/

Comment: Please answer with example. Link can rot